# Get variable on input name on Jquery

Tags: jquery, variables, input

i have the next on Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var asign=$('#asignatura').val();
    var id_user=$('#id_usuario').val();
    var id_pupil=$('#id_alumno').val();

    $("#agregar").on('click', function(){
        $('#tabla > tbody:last').after("<tr><td><input type='text' name='calification' value=''></td><td></td><td><a href='actualizar_notas.php?calificacion="+calification+" && asignatura="+asign+" && id_usuario="+id_user+" && id_alumno="+id_pupil+"'</a>agregar</td></tr>");


    });
```

And i would like to get on the "calification" written in input type text to pass by get on href.

That´s not work.

Anybody can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: What? "And i would like to get on the "calification" written in input type" -- Not sure what that means, can you clarify?

Comment: Yes, i have a row created dynamically which have 3 columns, the first has a input to write a number, the second it´s empty because when it´s stored on the database, shows the date, and the third is an add button to add to database. And i would like to get the value of the first column which is a number to have the name of variable to pass it by href with ?calification="+califications+".

Comment: '**' in the link ? it's a typo or you really have that in your code ?

Comment: No, that´s because i´ve tried here to put in bold but didn´t work, it´s not from the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#agregar").on('click', function(){

    var asign=$('#asignatura').val();
    var id_user=$('#id_usuario').val();
    var id_pupil=$('#id_alumno').val();

    $('#tabla > tbody:last').after("<tr><td></td><td></td><td><a href='actualizar_notas.php?calificacion="+calification+"&asignatura="+asign+"&id_usuario="+id_user+"&id_alumno="+id_pupil+"'>agregar</a></td></tr>");


});
```

Comment: It doesn´t work... Now, jquery doesn´t add any row when i press add

Comment: your snippet was full of typo, i've edited b4 your com, check & check your console for error - "it doesn't work is" ok from an content manager but from a dev...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$('input[name="calification"]').val()` to retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're asking is...

> When the user enters a value in the `input` and clicks the link, how can I add the entered value into the URL of the link?

The first thing you'll want to do is remove that value from the link in your existing code.  Since you don't have the value at the time that the code runs, there's nothing you can do about it there.  (You'll also want to fix the broken link, your code seems to be missing the rest of the opening `a` tag.  And fix the broken `&` concatenations in the URL itself.)

```
<a href='actualizar_notas.php?asignatura="+asign+"&id_usuario="+id_user+"&id_alumno="+id_pupil+"'>agregar</a>
```

Next, you'll want to handle the click event for that link manually.  Since the link is added dynamically and each one will have its own associated `input`, let's give the link a `class` so we can reference that in our handler:

```
<a class="agregarLink" href='actualizar_notas.php?asignatura="+asign+"&id_usuario="+id_user+"&id_alumno="+id_pupil+"'>agregar</a>
```

Now let's create the handler:

```
$('#tabla').on('click', 'a.agregarLink', function () {
    // Get the calification value that the user has entered (if any)
    // This should come from the input that's in the same table row as the clicked link
    var calification = $(this).parent('tr').find('input[name="calification"]').val();

    // Redirect the user as though they clicked on a link
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href') + '&calification=' + encodeURIComponent(calification);

    // Just in case the browser is still going to try to process the link directly
    return false;
});
```

That redirect *should* result in a complete URL to include any value entered (URL-encoded, of course).  Such as:

```
actualizar_notas.php?asignatura=someValue&id_usuario=anotherValue&id_alumno=aThirdValue&calification=aUserEnteredValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JS fiddle of this, using keypress in new input box

```
    var asign=$('#asignatura').val();
    var id_user=$('#id_usuario').val();
    var id_pupil=$('#id_alumno').val();
    var calification;
    $("#agregar").on('click', function(){
        $('#tabla > tbody:last').after("<tr><td><input type='text' id='calification' name='calification' value=''>Input box added</td><td></td><td><a href='' id='link'>I dont have any link now !! type in the input box </a>agregar</td></tr>");
    }); 
    $('#calification').live('keyup', function(){
        calification = $(this).val(); //alert(calification)
        var newHref = "actualizar_notas.php?calificacion="+calification+"&&asignatura="+asign+" && id_usuario="+id_user+" && id_alumno="+id_pupil+"";
        $('#link').attr('href', newHref).text('I have a link now ');
        $('#newlink').text(newHref);
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/abhiklpm/H2deA/1/

Comment: Now, when i press agregar doesn´t add any row. The button agregar doesn´t work...

Comment: First click "(Click me)" , then when input box appears type in that and you can see the link being generated below it.
I have altered it to use the other text box fields also:

[link]http://jsfiddle.net/abhiklpm/H2deA/2/